# How do you forward an event from one match block to the next in fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I came across Fluentd last week. I liked it at first (still do), but there seem to be a few holes that are preventing me from using it.

I'm trying to forward our logs to two different locations - an S3 bucket to archive, and an Elasticsearch database for analytics with kibana. I looked at the `fluent-forest-plugin`, but I realize that won't work because of [this](https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-forest/issues/15). I tried using the `copy` plugin, but I'm getting this error:

```
[error]: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error="Other 's3' plugin already use same buffer_path: type = s3, buffer_path = /tmp/fluent-plugin-s3"
```

with this config

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/web__error.log
  pos_file /var/tmp/nginx_web__error.pos
  tag web__error
  format /^(?<time>[^ ]+ [^ ]+) \[(?<log_level>.*)\] (?<pid>\d*).(?<tid>[^:]*): (?<message>.*)$/
</source>
<match web__error>
  type copy
  <store>
    type s3
    aws_key_id ACC_KEY
    aws_sec_key SEC_KEY
    s3_bucket log-bucket
    path web__error/
    buffer_path /tmp/fluent-plugin-s3
    s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}
    time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d/%H
    flush_interval 15s
    utc
  </store>
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix web__error
    flush_interval 15s
    include_tag_key true
    utc_index true
  </store>
</match>
```

**From what I've read, once an event is caught in one match block, it can't be caught by any subsequent ones. As a last resort, I need to know if there is any way to do this that I haven't found yet?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue - I forgot I was using the same `buffer_path` in other config files, which caused this error.